# Can you work out real power by taking the average of several measurements of instantaneous power?

Tags: power

Pretty simple answer to this, but I have managed to get myself into a lot of confusion

*Can you work out real power by taking the average of several measurements of instantaneous power?*

I was hoping that it is the case that way I would not need to measure the phase difference between the voltage and the current.

Comment: Should work if your sample rate is high enough.

Comment: If you already have a way to measure current, and the load is linear (and thus the current is also sinusoidal), then measuring the phase difference between the two is pretty easy. Simply time the difference between zero crossings of each.

Comment: I am currently measuring the current with a hall effect sensor. I was looking at the zero crossing but from what I have read it doesn't seem that easy for what I want. At least now I can look at a way of measuring the voltage that wont affect the rest of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although watch for aliasing.  After all, real power *is* the average power, usually averaged over a whole repeating cycle.

What you have to watch out for are high frequencies in the instantaneous power signal.  As when point-sampling any signal, the frequencies above half the sample rate become aliases, which is a form of noise on the sampled signal.  If the power signal has significant content above half your sample frequency, then you will get erroneous readings.

For example, consider a line-powered device that has a full wave bridge feeding a reservoir cap immediately on the power input.  The current will have significant high frequency content so that you have to sample much faster than twice per power line cycle to get meaningful readings.  Or, you can think of this same thing in the time domain.  The current will be short spikes near the voltage peaks.  If you sample such that you often miss these peaks, you are going to get the wrong idea of the average power.

Fortunately, modern microcontrollers can sample much much faster than the AC line frequency.  1000 samples per AC line cycles isn't overkill, but that's only 60 kHz sample rate, which is pretty slow compared to what many micros can do nowadays.  When trying to compute power and you think the waveforms won't be nice sinusoids, sample as fast as you can.

I should also point out that low pass filtering the voltage and current independently to avoid aliases, then computing power from these slower samples is not valid.  You can only average (low pass filter) *after* computing power from voltage and current, not before.  Put another way, the product of average current and average voltage does not yield average power.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer has saved me some work as I had started to make everything a lot more complicated then it needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you preserve the sign of the power (both positive and negative), and you have enough samples to get an accurate average, yes. Real power is defined as exactly the average of instantaneous power. Here's an image from Wikipedia:

[image: graph of AC power]

The instantaneous power (blue line) is the product of voltage and current, goes up and down, and sometimes even negative. The average power (cyan) is right in the middle, and is the real power.

Comment: Beat you by 7 seconds!